# jQuery mobile creates a blue border around my screen, how to remove?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, border, swipe

I have added **jQuery mobile** on my site to add swipes, to make my site more mobile friendly. link: [my site](http://www.klemen-lozar.com)

When you click anywhere on my page, a blue border in chrome(pc) will appear around the page, on my android mobile chrome the border is in yellow. I just want to get rid of it because it makes page ugly.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: You are right, I am sorry, however, I just found a solution:
**.ui-page-active{
outline:none;
}**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick fix is to remove this outline through **css**

> .ui-page-active { outline: none; }

Done!